# How can I find out what classification types are registered in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I can use `IClassificationTypeRegistryService.GetClassificationType` to get classification types. This is great and I can get the predefined types lists here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.standardclassification.predefinedclassificationtypenames.aspx

I've also been able to find some types registered by other languages such as "cppType". I can't remember how I found out what the names are for other types and need to access some more.

How do I enumerate the available classification types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found I can hover over an instance of IClassificationTypeRegistryService in the debugger and inspect a private member which is an array that lists them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)